# Firebase Database stops working during scene transition

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

When I am trying to use Firebase Database independently on different scenes on the Unity Editor, it works fine.

But when I am trying to make Firebase work through scene transition, it works on the first scene but it doens't work in the second scene.

This happens both on the editor and on device.

Comment: The object your script resides on, is it being destroyed during scene transitions? You probably need to add `DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); ` to the Awake() function of your script.

Comment: The "Firebase Services" object which is used for the working of Firebase, the doesn't get destroyed. And as I said, there are two independent scripts on two different scenes. Both work properly when played independently, but the second doesn't work on transition